# Register an ElasticSearch query with the Percolator using the Java API

Tags: elasticsearch

I am trying to use ElasticSearch's Percolator feature; doing this via the curl examples from the documentation is straightforward enough, as is percolating a document using the Java API. What I can't find out how to do is registering a query with the percolator using the Java API - how is this done?

Using the example from the documentation, how would I do this in Java?

```
curl -XPUT localhost:9200/_percolator/test/kuku -d '{
    "query" : {
        "term" : {
            "field1" : "value1"
        }
    }
}'
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`_percolator` is just an index. You register queries with it by indexing queries as you normally would index documents:

```
client.prepareIndex("_percolator", "test", "kuku")
    .setSource(jsonBuilder().startObject()
        .field("query", termQuery("field1", "value1"))
        .endObject())
    .setRefresh(true)
    .execute().actionGet()
```

You can also check [elasticsearch integration tests](https://github.com/elasticsearch/elasticsearch/blob/master/src/test/java/org/elasticsearch/percolator/PercolatorTests.java) for more examples.

**EDIT:** The link above is dead, you might want to take a look at the official documentation [here](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/integration-tests.html) concerning the *integration tests*.

I have also added a gist of the old PercolatorTests class on [gist](https://gist.github.com/eliasah/2d9dab2adb93cdda5500).

Comment: The Github link has been changed to https://github.com/elasticsearch/elasticsearch/blob/master/src/test/java/org/elasticsearch/percolator/PercolatorTests.java.